# невозможно открыть .chproj в VS (CryEngine)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, разработка-игр

задача написать хоть что-нибудь и с ограничениям:

1. на Unity слишком просто, Unity нельзя
2. BluePrint в Unreal Engine и подобные средства разработки запрещены.

Я решил написать C# проект на CryEngine последней версии
(Не знаю почему именно игра, а не какое-нибудь веб приложение для расчета расходов на день. Просто хочется, тем более уже пытался делать кое-что на Unity).

при попытке открыть C# скрипт в ассетах происходит следующее:

[image: попытка открыть C# скрипт]

у меня стоит VS 2019 Community и вот что выводит если нажать OK:

[image: После нажатия ОК]

вот куда ведет ссылка https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?utm_source=getvssdk&utm_medium=referral&view=vs-2019

файл открывается, но не видно изменений в самом cry engine. Видел ролик где генерируют (solution) из CryEngine проекта но происходит то же самое.

стоило ли брать Cry Engine? Может переключиться на что-либо другое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сори, надо было установить расширение Mono